# How to access a freeform field object's properties from an event

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-freeform, solspace, freeform

I am trying to get the value of a field from a freeform event.  Specifically I'm trying to see if a particular checkbox is in a form submission.

```
craft()->on(
    "freeform_submissions.onBeforeSave",
    function (Event $event) {
        $submission = $event->params["model"];
        $field = $submission['fieldMetadata']['checkbox_handle'];
```

This works to this point.  I see if I do `Craft:dd($field);` I have a checkboxField object. But from here on I can't get any info about that field.

```
        $id = $field->id; // or:
        $handle = $field->handle; // and any other properties
```

This throws: `Fatal error: Cannot access protected property Solspace\Freeform\Library\Composer\Components\Fields\CheckboxField::$id`.

If I try:

```
        $id = $field['id'];
```

I get: `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type Solspace\Freeform\Library\Composer\Components\Fields\CheckboxField as array`

The properties and methods are listed at: https://solspace.com/craft/freeform/docs/field/, but I can't access the properties.  I can call the `render()` method which works and that outputs html.  I'm sure its something obvious, but I'm missing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question, this is what I found.
The answer is to use `get...` methods.

```
craft()->on(
    "freeform_submissions.onBeforeSave",
    function (Event $event) {
        $submission = $event->params["model"];
        $field_item = $submission->fieldMetadata['field_handle'];
        $field_value = $field_item->getValue();

    }
);
```

The `$field_item->getValue()` can be `$field_item->getId()` or `$field_item->getHandle()` and so on.

The properties listed here: https://solspace.com/craft/freeform/docs/field/ can be used by turning the property into a method and prepending `get`.